# Find the largest integer $n$ such that $n$ has exactly 4 positive divisors and $n$ divides $100!$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

Find the largest integer $n$ such that $n$ has exactly 4 positive divisors and $n$ divides $100!$.

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Such $n$ should have prime factors that are exactly the two largest primes smaller than $100$.

Comment: @user340297 and that $n$ can only be of form $p^3$ or $pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes

Comment: Consider which kinds of numbers have precisely four positive divisors.

Comment: Have a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698962/what-positive-integers-has-exactly-n-divisors-for-n-from-1-to-5

Comment: @user340297 . Or $n=p^3$ where p is prime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number $n$ with prime decomposition $$n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdot p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdot \ldots\cdot p_r^{\alpha_r}$$
has $$\sigma_0(n)=(1+\alpha_1)(1+\alpha_2)\ldots(1+\alpha_r)$$
positive divisors. Since we want $\sigma_0(n)=4$ we get the possible exponent spectra $(3)$ and $(1,1)$, i.e.,
$$n=p^3\quad \vee \quad n=p\,q\ .$$
If $\ p^3\>|\>100!$ then at least three multiples of $p$ (namely $p$, $2p$, $3p$) have to be $\leq100$. The largest $p$ fulfilling this requirement is $31$, hence $n=31^3=29\,791$.

The option $n=p\,q$ lets us choose the largest two primes $\leq100$, which leads to $n=97\cdot 89=8633<29\,791$.

Comment: I worked out  $(97)(89)<(31)^3 $ mentally by $\frac {(31)^3}{(89)(97)}=$ $\frac {31}{(97//31)(89/31)}>$ $\frac {31}{(4)(3)}>1.$